# Direct sound playback via HDMI with sound input from Bluetooth Mic

Tags: pi-3, audio, hdmi, bluetooth, pulseaudio

I've connected my Raspberry Pi to a TV via HDMI, by default the sound output is through TV speakers via HDMI.

I installed `pulseaudio` and successfully connected a Bluetooth headset [samsung HM1100] to the RP. Now, I can input/output sound via Bluetooth mic and Bluetooth speaker of the headset but when I'm connected to Bluetooth headset device I can never hear sound from TV speakers [HDMI].

For one of my project I want to direct sound output through HDMI **and** keep the Bluetooth mic connected, how could I do that?

Comment: Welcome to the Raspberry Pi flavoured corner of the Stack Exchange network.  You may wish to take the [tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to help you get the most out of the SE network.  I think your question can be answered by the correct configuration of your _multiple_ sound sources/sinks that `pulseaudio` will see you have - lets see if someone can give a good explaination...